# How to play youtube videos in my windows phone app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

Hi i want to play you tube videos in my windows phone app.i am new for windows phone,i dont have any experience in playing videos in my application.Please help me anyone how to play you tube videos in application.

my code is given below

xml file

```
<FullContent>
  <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2o-Y0RzSfkE?fs=0" width="500" height="298" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="false" ></iframe>
</FullContent>
```

xaml file

```
<StackPanel  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="600" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="title" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40"></TextBlock>
    <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" Height="600"  IsScriptEnabled="True" />
```

xaml.cs file

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string video = "<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2o-Y0RzSfkE?fs=0" width="500" height="298" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="false" ></iframe>"
        this.Navigate.ToString(video);
    }
```

I tried above the code but i got only black color box.i cant play you tube video.so please help me anyone.Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use the YouTube class that is available in the MyToolkit library for Windows Phone, take a look [here...](https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=YouTube&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: Hi thank you for your replay.already i tried that YouTube class but i don't know how to write that code.So please can you help me?Please write sample code.

Comment: If you download the source code it contains a YouTube example! https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/28598

Comment: Hi @Depechie i have downloaded source code.that have so many source code,i dont know how to get that.If you have team viewer please come and resolve my issue.am a new for windows phone that's why i am asking like that.

Comment: Otherwise, here is the exact link to the example page with the correct code: https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/28598#309593

Comment: I am a new developer.I am working one low level company.i can't hire you.Just i am asking help to you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29113/discussion-between-user123-and-depechie)

Comment: @user123 can you get your solution of 'play a youtube videos directly in your windows phone App?'
or yet not ?

Answer (score 0):

```
web.NavigateToString("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 3.2//EN' 'http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd'>" +
"<iframe width='320' height='200' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + kk + "' frameborder='0' >'</iframe>");
```

kk=youtube video id